# Is there a way to remove powerpoint objects from a powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a powerpoint that contains shapes. I'd like to create another powerpoint with the exact appearance but rendered objects into pictures. The reason is I need to import the powerpoint in another program which does fully support powerpoint shapes. If each page contains a picture instead it should work.

I tried to export it into pdf and used www.pdftoppt.com to convert it back to ppt but the latter objectifies it again.

Comment: Do you want to render the slides as pictures, or only the objects in the slides as pictures

Comment: everything not just objects.

Comment: Please specify your OS and Office Version

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Powerpoint 2013, then hit F12, then save it as PowerPoint Picture Presentation.

It will convert all your slides into pictures, and keep the presentation intact.

Comment: I have PowerPoint for Mac 2011. I don't see that option here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this work around

Create new folder with your project name

Save your ppt as pictures (File > save As > JPEG File interchange format)

[image]

This will save all your slides as pictures(Slide number = picture number)

[image]

Open new ppt and go to option (Insert > photo album > open your project folder > select all images (ctrl+a)) and click insert

[image]

This will insert all images as slides, (picture number = slide number)

[image]

Note: This slides will be inserted as images and not as objects

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice solution, I'll try it next time.